# Pyspark map from RDD of strings to RDD of list of doubles

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I believe in the context of programming in spark / python that this is a reasonably basic operation. I have a text file that looks as such:

```
mydata.txt
12  34  2.3  15
23  11  1.5  9
33  18  4.5  99
```

and then I use the following code to read in the textfile:

```
data = sc.textFile("mydata.txt")
```

and this reads in the file as an RDD of strings. However I want to separate the values and convert them all into floats. So I change the line above to this:

```
data = sc.textFile("matrix1.txt").map(lambda line: line.split(' '))
```

which successfully splits the data by spaces. However I am struggling to come up with the map function that then converts to floats. something along the lines of:

```
.map(lambda line: float(line))
```

but this didn't work. Any help appreciated!
Thanks!

EDIT - please assume I do not know the number of columns of the data. so something along the lines of .map(lambda line: float(line[0]), float(line[1]), float(line[2]), float(line[3])) is not particularly helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, got it.

```
.map(lambda line: [float(x) for x in line])
```